# Generic interface keys from other interface key values (typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I want to create an interface that limits me to the values received from another,
My Original thought was to derive from the values such as

```
interface Foo = {
   id: string
} 
interface Bar = {
  [values of id]
}
const FooObject: Foo = {
   id: "what",
}

const BarObject: Bar = {
  what: "whatever" // Pass
  wha: "whatever" // Fail
}
```

Then tried the other way around and failed as well

```
interface Bar = {
  [ANY KEY]: string | number;
  onClick: () => void; // need this since react 
}

interface Foo = {
   id: [keys of Bar] 
} 

const BarObject: Bar = {
  what: "whatever",
  wha: "whatever" ,
}

const FooObject: Foo = {
   id: "what", // will allow only "what" | "wha"
}
```

Please help me if this is even possible, I'm pretty sure I've seen a solution like this using generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not infer literal values in object types, so the type of `id` in `FooObject` is simply `string` (and not `"what"`).

You can use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to force the compiler to infer literal, readonly values, like in the example below. By doing so, you can then use the inferred type of `FooObject` in place of the [constrained generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` in `Bar` to achieve the goal that you described.

> See also:
>
> - the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)
> - the [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-FAABQARgAzAA2AAMAEooHihs1xZK+mYNepFAM7aC0uggA)

```ts
type Foo = {
  id: string;
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type Bar<T extends Record<PropertyKey, string>> = Record<Values<T>, unknown>;

const FooObject = {
  id: "what",
} as const satisfies Foo;
//^^^^^^^^
// Using a const assertion forces the compiler to infer literal values

const BarObject = {
  what: "whatever", // OK
  wha: "whatever", /* NOK
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Type '{ what: string; wha: string; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'Bar<{ readonly id: "what"; }>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'wha' does not exist in type
  'Bar<{ readonly id: "what"; }>'. Did you mean to write 'what'? (1360) */
} satisfies Bar<typeof FooObject>;
```